# How to find difference in dates in zend and add it into a database

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is the function in my controller lesson_from and lesson_to is the fields where i get date.
i need to find the difference between the date and calculate no of days between them and add it into the data

```
    ----------


     public function applyAction()
        {
            if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
            {
                try
                {
                    $posts=$this->params()->fromPost();
                    if (!isset($posts['l_type']) ) {
                        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage("Sorry please fill in all required fields!");
                        return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/employee/apply');
                    }

                    //print_r($posts);die;
                $this->getEM()->getRepository('Application\Model\Leaves');
                $firstDay= $posts['lesson_from'];//date
                $lastDay=$posts['lesson-to'];//date
                $diff = $lastDay->sub($firstDay)->toValue();
                $days = ceil($diff/60/60/24) +1;

               $leaves = new Leaves();
               $leaves->setEmployee('test')
                   ->setDays($days)
                   ->setStatus('Pending')
                   ->setDate(new \DateTime($posts['lesson-from']))
                   ->setComments($posts['comments'])
                   ->setType($posts['l_type']);


                    $this->getEM()->persist($leaves);
                    $this->getEM()->flush();
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage("Successfully saved new album!");
                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/employee');

                }
                catch(\Exception $e)
                {
                    error_log($e->getMessage());
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage("Some error occurred !");
                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/employee/apply');
                }
            }

            return new ViewModel();
        }


    -----
```

And now am getting these errors too

---

[Wed Feb 26 10:37:11 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lesson_from in /var/www/leavemanagement/module/Employee/src/Employee/Controller/EmployeeController.php on line 58, referer: http://leavemanagement.localhost/employee/apply
[Wed Feb 26 10:37:11 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function sub() on a non-object in /var/www/leavemanagement/module/Employee/src/Employee/Controller/EmployeeController.php on line 60, referer: http://leavemanagement.localhost/employee/apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 **$datetime1 = date_create($posts['lesson-from']);
                $datetime2 = date_create($posts['lesson-to']);
                $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
                $days = $interval->format('%R%a days');**
               $leaves = new Leaves();
               $leaves->setEmployee('test')
                   ->setDays($days)
                   ->setStatus('Pending')
                   ->setDate(new \DateTime($posts['lesson-from']))
                   ->setComments($posts['comments'])
                   ->setType($posts['l_type']);
```